# kernel and installed packages

Tags: kernel

Ubuntu comes with several different variants of the kernel. I am talking about the different kernel version that you can select at boot time.

Say I am on kernel 4.4.1, and I installed the package nfs-common. Then I switch to kernel 4.4.2. Should the nfs-common still be there? I guess it shouldn't right?